# bluedart api pincode search not working in php for api integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

Any one please to help me i have one problem in blue dart api error. NO Error is came. how to solve this problem.

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
 function soaprequest($api_url, $api_username, $api_password, $service, $params)
{
    if ($api_url != '' && $service != '' && count($params) > 0)
    {
        $wsdl = $api_url."?wsdl";
        $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl');
        $client->setCredentials($api_username,$api_password);
        $error = $client->getError();
        if ($error)
        {
            echo "\nSOAP Error\n".$error."\n";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $client->call($service, $params);
            if ($client->fault)
            {
                print_r($result);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $result_arr = json_decode($result, true);
                $return_array = $result_arr['result'];
                return $return_array;
            }
        }
    }
}

$api_url = "http://netconnect.bluedart.com/ver1.7/Demo/ShippingAPI/Finder/ServiceFinderQuery.svc?wsdl";
//$api_url = "http://netconnect.bluedart.com/ Demo/ShippingAPI/Finder/ServiceFinderQuery.svc?wsdl";
$api_username='XXXXXXXXXX';
$api_password = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
$service ='GetServicesforPincode';
$params = array('pinCode'=>'620102');
soaprequest($api_url, $api_username, $api_password, $service, $params);
```

above code is download from codeigniter library and it have also not working

Answer (score 0):

the url you are supplying terminates with `?wsdl` but inside the `soaprequest` function `?wsdl` gets appended to the url so I guess your url would look like

```
http://netconnect.bluedart.com/ver1.7/Demo/ShippingAPI/Finder/ServiceFinderQuery.svc?wsdl?wsdl
```

which doesn't seem right so try without the `?wsdl` at the end of the url?